# Скачать Excel-файл после ajax-запроса

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Всем привет, я отправляю ajax-запрос на сервер для формирования отчета и мне надо его как-то скачать. Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/unloading/reportExcel/',
        type: 'post',
        data: { 
                name: _name,
                startDate: _startDate,
                endDate: _endDate,
                objType: _objType,
            },
    })
    .success(function (data) {
        alert('report ready');
    })
    .done(function(data){
        $('#name_rep').val('');
        $('#osx_reportExcel_close_btn').click();
    })
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ){
         err= 'err!' + "\n" + jqXHR.status + "\n" + jqXHR.statusText;
         alert( err );

    })
```

PHP:

```
public static function action_reportExcel(){
//code
createExcelFile($insert_row, $update_row);
}
public static function createExcelFile($insert, $update){
        //code
        b_clean();
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="otchet.xlsx"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
     
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Type: application/download"); 
        header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
        header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
        header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
        header ('Location : index.php');
 
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
        exit;
}
```

Но файл скачивается, если только через devtools-> сеть перейти по запросу самому.

Всем благодарен за помощь!

**Не скачивается в Firefox и Opera! Но Google почему-то работает**

Comment: А зачем тут ajax, собственно?))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**
Можно при клике на кнопку сформировать ссылку на которую программно кликнуть. Это было бы лучше, как мне кажется. И для это вовсе не нужен ajax

---

**2.**

Можно использовать атрибут *HTML* [Атрибут download](http://htmlbook.ru/html/a/download), чтобы сразу сделать там ссылку и если пользователь кликнет - скачать файл.

---

**3.**  Попробуйте так:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/unloading/reportExcel/',
    type: 'post',
    data: { 
            name: _name,
            startDate: _startDate,
            endDate: _endDate,
            objType: _objType,
        },
})
.success(function (data) {
    alert('report ready');
})
.done(function(data){
    /* МАГИЯ ЗДЕСЬ */
    let blob = new Blob([data]);
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = "<FILENAME_TO_SAVE_WITH_EXTENSION>";
    link.click();
    /* МАГИЯ ЗДЕСЬ */

    $('#name_rep').val('');
    $('#osx_reportExcel_close_btn').click();
})
.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ){
     err= 'err!' + "\n" + jqXHR.status + "\n" + jqXHR.statusText;
     alert( err );

})
```

---

**4.** Можно использовать [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html)

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '<URL_TO_FILE>',
  success: download.bind(true, "<FILENAME_TO_SAVE_WITH_EXTENSION>", "<FILE_MIME_TYPE>")
});
```

Comment: Первый вариант я пробовал изначально, но он не работает как только в дело вступает кириллица. Остальные сейчас буду пробовать. Спасибо

Comment: @DanzoSama что значит "как только в дело вступает кириллица"?

Comment: я формировал ссылку и вот так выполнял, работает если name=&, но не если name="Русский текст"  ( document.location.href = "/unloading/reportExcel?name="+_name; )

Comment: @DanzoSama Возможно вам нужно это кодировать. Например  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI  или https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: При формировании ссылки, я не добавлял знак "&" после текста, который похоже и является разделителем. Спасибо за предложенные способы!